# How to get public access to edit a layer in geoserver

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I want to develop a GIS system with OpenLayers and GeoServer which is installed with OpenGeo Suite 4.1 and I need to edit a layer with no GeoServer authentication. This means that guest members should have permission to edit a layer.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Service access rules list" page has a rule that only "ADMIN" roles have permission for WFS-Transaction.

```
wfs.Transation --> ADMIN
```

You must delete this rule.